# Is there a way to configure a default typemapping for the UUID type

Tags: hibernate

I know how to map UUID's to `varchar` using Hibernate's `@Type` mapping. However, I wonder if there is a way to tell Hibernate (in a Spring Boot app) to use this `@Type("uuid-char")` whenever it encounters a `UUID` in an entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to override `contributeTypes` method for your hibernate dialect. See, for example, [PostgreSQL82Dialect](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL82Dialect.java#L29).
2. The added in this way type should also override `registerUnderJavaType` like [PostgresUUIDType](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/PostgresUUIDType.java#L46) does it. But `UUIDCharType` does not do it.

So, you can declare your own type, like below:

```java
import org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect;
import org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType;
import org.hibernate.type.LiteralType;
import org.hibernate.type.StringType;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.UUIDTypeDescriptor;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor;

public class MyUUIDCharType extends AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<UUID> implements LiteralType<UUID>
{
   public static final MyUUIDCharType INSTANCE = new MyUUIDCharType();

   public MyUUIDCharType() {
      super( VarcharTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE, UUIDTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE );
   }

   @Override
   public String getName() {
      return "my-uuid-char";
   }

   @Override
   protected boolean registerUnderJavaType() {
      // register this type under UUID when it is added to the basic type registry
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public String objectToSQLString(UUID value, Dialect dialect) throws Exception {
      return StringType.INSTANCE.objectToSQLString( value.toString(), dialect );
   }
}
```

and then register it:

```java
public class MyPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQL95Dialect
{
   // ...
   
   @Override
   public void contributeTypes(TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry)
   {
      typeContributions.contributeType( MyUUIDCharType.INSTANCE );
   }
}
```

But if you are going to use `UUID` as a PK please note that saving `UUID` as a string can lead to the performance issue, as it explained in [this article](https://tomharrisonjr.com/uuid-or-guid-as-primary-keys-be-careful-7b2aa3dcb439):

> Aside from the 9x cost in size (36 vs. 4 bytes for an int), strings don’t sort as fast as numbers because they rely on collation rules.

Look also at [HHH-9577](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9577).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately: override in a custom dialect class does not work as a 'default'. Still need to annotate with `@Type`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that was the missing link. Works like a charm!